# How can I 'ssh' to an ubuntu server running on VirutalBox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, ssh, nat

I have installed Ubuntu Server on a virtual machine in VirtualBox which runs on Windows 7.
How can I connect through ssh to that virtual machine?

I go and type 'ifconfig', and i get this address "10.0.2.15". But when I try `ssh 10.0.2.15` it can't establish the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to set up the network interface of the virtual machine to "Bridged mode" in virtualbox.

You do that by selecting the virtual machine (in VB) then go to `settings > network`, and change the `attached to` dropdown from `NAT` to  `bridged`

After that, you virtual machine should get an IP address of your local network (similar tot he one of the host pc) and you should be able to ssh it with that IP.

Comment: Actually you don't need to set it up in bridged mode, but bridged mode is the easiest way to solve your issue. If you want to keep your machine in NAT, you have to do a port forward rule in your virtualbox machine NAT settings.

Comment: thanks tomodachi, i updated the answer to reflect it's the easiest and not the only way

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by forwarding ports to the virtual machine.
Make sure your virtual machine has `openssh-server` installed and running!

> Open VirtualBox -> Click on your VM -> "Settings" -> "Network" -> "Advanced" -> "Port Forwarding"

Click the icon in the top right which has a plus (+) symbol to add a port forwarding rule and enter the following data:

```
Name: ssh (or whatever you want)
Protocol: TCP
Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host port: 2222
Guest port: 22
```

Note that the host port is *not* the usual `ssh` port of 22.
Now you can ssh into your virtual machine!

```
ssh user@localhost -p 2222
```